# Print a Resources.resx file value within ASP.NET tags

Tags: asp.net, .net, resources

I'm required to print a value of a  string which within a resource files `(.resx)` within asp.net tags

i used the following approaches

for example  :

```
<ext:ComboBox ID="cmbProgram" runat="server" FieldLabel="<%= Resource.StringName %>"

<ext:ComboBox ID="cmbProgram" runat="server" FieldLabel="<%= Response.Write(Resource.StringName) %>"
```

But both approaches didin't provide the **value** of the string, but provides the ID. How to get the values within the ASP.NET tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `Control.ascx`:

```
<ext:Tag runat="server" meta:resourcekey="fooBar" />
```

Then put `Controls.ascx.resx` in `App_LocalResources` containing appropriate strings:

```
fooBar.PropetyName = "x"
```

Comment: actually i required to to print a value from a `Control.ascx` [Other way around]

Comment: @Sudantha: ASP.NET will read Control.ascx.resx and set a value of appropriate property. Why don't you prefer such solution?